# How to debug permission problems

Tags: 9

I already found answers for older versions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17214/how-do-i-debug-permissions) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202671/debug-access-denied) but as far as I can tell none of it directly translates into drupal 9.

The matter in practice: I don't have a huge experience but I was very surprised when in the not so complicated setup I'm building I could see the page of a taxonomy term but none of the items in it under the introductory text when viewing the page as anonymous user. Viewing one of the nodes by direct url results in "Access Denied".

Not much at play, all items are published, permissions look good and I already rebuilt permissions and caches so I'm looking for something like raw printing yay/nay permissions being applied and so on. Even looking directly in the database would be ok if applicable.

Comment: This could be several things, not just permissions. The default view could have been modified, a contributed or custom module may have hijacked the route, is the Main Content block set to not show on term routes, etc. this question needs more information on the setup.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your comment, I should have added that if I point directly to one of the nodes in the view I get "Access Denied" so, at least, it's not (only?) a view/block problem. The anonymous user is actually not allowed to see the nodes. Updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was all my fault, and very simple: I had not yet defined the default domain in the **Domain Access** module. The question still stands however, as I could not find ways to debug permissions applicable to Drupal 9. So this is my answer to the original problem but not an answer to the more generic task.